# Clarification on [mac] and [osx]

Tags: discussion, tags

Relevant tag information

[mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac):

> Hardware related questions of computers sold/made by Apple. Use [osx]
> for the operating system, and use [mac-address] for MAC addresses
> instead.

[osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx):

> A Unix-based operating system developed and sold by Apple Inc. For Mac
> hardware questions, use [mac].

---

All of the threads I could find on meta are from *at least* 4 years ago. Since **mac** is for hardware and **osx** is for the ***operating system***, it's unclear to me (upon reading the tag excerpts from a new user perspective) how one would tag a question about software on a mac.

E.G. [microsoft-excel-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2011),[microsoft-excel-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2008) and [microsoft-excel-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2002) all read

> [...] Microsoft's spreadsheet application for Mac.

Since [microsoft-excel-2016](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2016) is cross-platform, it stands to reason that if you're using a mac, you need to add the tag [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) rather than [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac), despite the trend from how the other excel tags are worded using ***mac***.

Reading that [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) is for the operating system might lead a user to think it's not the right tag.

#### Suggestion

Include in the [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) excerpt language that it applies to software running on the operating system, not just the operating system itself.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, Excel for Mac is actually Excel for OSX, but it's not named that way. However, I adjusted the tag wiki excerpts to be clearer in Super User terms.

If you're using a software that works on multiple platforms, and your problem is likely specific to the platform you're using it on, then it is right to include the platform tag. Including the model of hardware you're using is very unlikely to be helpful or relevant.